# Ksh script issue

Tags: awk, ksh

script:

```
 rec_len=`awk -v l="$col_rec_len" -v count=0 '{if(length($0)!=l) {printf "%s:%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR,length($0), $0  >> "/dev/stderr"
                     count++ }
                     }  END {print count}' $input 2>> $logfile`
```

I was trying to get the no of records having the length issue for a fixed width file in variable rec_len  . the issue is above command is counting the \n too. how to avoid the same

Comment: It wouldn't count `\n`s but it might find some `\r`s if the files are in Microsoft format, in which case, you'd want to convert them to Unix format with dos2unix or d2u first.

Comment: yes i did dos to unix and the script worked thank you

Comment: Never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. Also `>> "/dev/stderr"` should be `> "/dev/stderr"` (awk is not shell) and you don't need `-v count=0`, just make the final print `print count+0` to ensure numeric output. Finally, quote your variables: use `"$input"`, not `$input`.